# How to convert a node object to JSON object in alfresco java webscript?

Tags: alfresco

I am wondering if there's a method to convert a Noderef to a json object in Java webscripts. I think I came across this or something similar not too long ago but can't find it any longer or remember where I saw it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
appUtils.toJSON(node, true);
```

The boolean true/false is for using short Qnames. [Here](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-toJSON.html) is some info about it.